# How can I make test cases inside a Class using pytest

Tags: python, class, pytest

First of all if I didn't formulat the question in a correct way, Sorry I tried my best.

I made a question an hour ago, but it was not in English, and to make another question I had to wait 40min.
However my question was: **how can I make a class that inside has test cases using pytest**

I did my research and I found a code that matches what I want, however it doesn't use pytest, instead it uses unittest, if I didn't explain myself I will let the code that I found if it helps as an example:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

def test_upper(self):
    self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

def test_isupper(self):
    self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
    self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

def test_split(self):
    s = 'hello world'
    self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
    # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In the code that I included, it uses Unittest and it takes unitest.TeslaCase as argument.
Is there any way to do it with pytest?, that instead of using unittest I could use pytest?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can just create any class (not derived from anything) with tests for pytest. The class name just has to start with `Test`. You can use that same example and run it using pytest (with or without deriving it from `TestCase`).

Comment: And it has to have any parameter like self or anything like that?

Comment: If you use a class, you need the `self` argument for methods, of course, except you make them static. If you don't derive from `TestCase`, you also have to replace the `assertXXX` by `assert` calls.

Comment: I appreciate a lot your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test_StringMethods():

    def test_upper(self):
        assert ('foo'.upper() == 'FOO'), "FAILED"

    def test_isupper(self):
        assert 'FOO'.isupper(), "FAILED"
        assert not 'Foo'.isupper(), "FAILED"

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        assert s.split() == ['hello', 'world'], "FAILED"
```